# seaborn setting in Julia via PyCall

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, julia, seaborn

I use seaborn for plotting in julia. However, I can't figure out how to parse on certaiin properties for set_style, e.g. the line in python would be

```
sns.set_style('darkgrid', {'axes.linewidth': 2, 'axes.edgecolor':'black'})
```

To give a minimal example:

```
using PyPlot
using PyCall
@pyimport seaborn as sns


test_plot()
function test_plot()
  clf()
  #- - -
  sns.set_style("ticks",???)
  # - - -
  tmp_plt=figure("plot1",figsize=(4.5, 3.5))
  x=collect(0:0.5:3)
  plot(x,0.4.*x)
  plot(x,x.^0.5)
end
```

Does anyone know how to replace '???' in julia so that it corresponds to the python input `{'axes.linewidth': 2, 'axes.edgecolor':'black'}`?

Thanks a lot:)

EDIT:
I found a workaround using rc for future references:

```
using PyPlot
using PyCall
@pyimport seaborn as sns

close()
test_plot()
function test_plot()
  sns.set_context("notebook", font_scale=1.4)
  sns.set_style("ticks")
  rc("font",family ="Computer Modern Roman")
  rc("lines",linewidth = 2.5)
  rc("axes",linewidth = 2,edgecolor=".55")
  rc("axes",grid=true)
  rc("grid",linestyle="-",color="1.0")
  rc("legend",frameon=true,edgecolor="none",facecolor="0.85")
  rc("axes",facecolor="0.96")
  rc("axes",titlesize="large")
  tmp_plt=figure("plot1",figsize=(8, 6))
  ax=gca()
  x=collect(0:0.5:3)
  plot(x,0.4.*x)
  plot(x,x.^0.5)
  tmp=legend(["Tmp 1", "Tmp 2"],loc=2,bbox_to_anchor=[0.0015,0.997],borderaxespad=0)
  xlabel("basic x",labelpad =5.0)
  ylabel("basic y",labelpad =5.0)
  title("\$ \\sum x^2\$",y=1.08)
  tight_layout()
  savefig("fig2.pdf")
end
```

Comment: Why are you involving seaborn? (and also why use PyPlot when you could use Plots.jl with the PyPlot backend)

Comment: @LyndonWhite perhaps the OP is just getting their feet wet with Julia and is relying on a familiar package. Seaborn is built off of matplotlib and provides a convenient and powerful interface for statistical plotting.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about seaborn, but the Julia equivalent to the Python

```
{'axes.linewidth': 2, 'axes.edgecolor':'black'}
```

is simply

```
Dict("axes.linewidth" => 2, "axes.edgecolor" => "black")
```